How does ML / AI models can help us in high throughput screening studies?
I am a chemist interested in applying fast methods to search for suitable molecular candidates for several applications (let's say HOMO LUMO gaps, excitation energies, etc.) As a consequence, I stumbled upon many many papers that apply ML/AI methods since they can learn from DFT/CC/MP... methods and thus give reliable results in a short time.
I recently attended a course about ML-based MD (using DeepMD, MACE, etc) and they repeated several times that ML/AI models are good at interpolating and NOT extrapolating.
As a result, if I wanted to spot a molecular candidate with intriguing properties, I cannot expect an ML model trained on known molecules to spot such a candidate, right? It feels like I am asking the ML model to detect an outlier but I have been reading the use of these methods for high-throughput screening over and over.

I think you should clarify how you'd plan to build the model (where would you get your data? could you procure samples and generate new data (experimental validation)?) and use it (would you make predictions about sets of molecules for which you have no data, and make selections? would you generate de novo candidates?). The field is vast, there is indeed a lot you could potentially do, but some approach should be chosen first. True, ML may have trouble extrapolating. Then you could use active learning to improve your model. For that you'll need a model that predicts its own uncertainty.

Screening amounts to using a sieve to detect molecules with features of interest. For a human those features may be impossible to identify, but a model can be generated (trained) that identifies them. There is no extrapolation when screening a molecular library with an existing model. I am not familiar with AI/MD methods however or what they add or where extrapolation might be involved.
